# why css not working

Tags: html, css, selector

css id selector not working  .. I cannot see wrong codes

**when  I do not use id  selector, code is working  but not working with id selector. I use id with single qouta and double but still not work** 
css id selector not working  .. I cannot see wrong codes

```
#ss {
  thead {
    display: block;
  }
  tbody {
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 350px;
  }
  table {
    width: 10px;
  }
  th,
  td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  }
  td {
    width: 60px;
  }
  th {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
  }
  tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #f2f2f2
  }
  tr:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
  }
}



<html>

<table id='ss'>
  <thead>
    <th>No</th>
    <th>Grup</th>
    <th>Barkod</th>
    <th>Urn_Adı</th>

  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr id='a1'>

      <td>1</td>
      <td id='a1_0'></td>
      <td id='a1_1'></td>
      <td id='a1_2'>NUANS</td>
      <td id='a1_3'>NUANS</td>

    <tr id='a2'>

      <td>2</td>
      <td id='a2_0'></td>
      <td id='a2_1'></td>
      <td id='a2_2'>SKEMER</td>
      <td id='a2_3'>WEMSEY</td>

    </tr>

  </tbody>

</table>
</html>
```

Comment: What you have posted is not valid CSS, are you using a CSS compiler like SASS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have given SASS, normal CSS can't use nested selectors like that.

You need to use a compiler.
Eg: http://www.sassmeister.com/ (Online) or http://koala-app.com/ (App)

It would compile down to:

```
#ss thead {
  display: block;
}
#ss tbody {
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 350px;
}
#ss table {
  width: 10px;
}
#ss th,
#ss td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
#ss td {
  width: 60px;
}
#ss th {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}
#ss tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
#ss tr:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

I just pulled this compiled CSS from the site I linked, so it may not do what you want it to do, but it's what you supplied.

Looking at your html, your SASS should be:

```
#ss {
  width: 10px;
  thead {
    display: block;
  }
  tbody {
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 350px;
  }
  th,
  td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  }
  td {
    width: 60px;
  }
  th {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
  }
  tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #f2f2f2
  }
  tr:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
  }
}
```

As the #ss selector is the table.
This would compile down to:

```
#ss {
  width: 10px;
}
#ss thead {
  display: block;
}
#ss tbody {
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 350px;
}
#ss th,
#ss td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
#ss td {
  width: 60px;
}
#ss th {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}
#ss tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
#ss tr:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not `SASS`... you can't use nested selectors in `CSS`

Answer (score 0):

```
#ss {
  thead {
    display: block;
  }
```

You can not nest rules like that in normal CSS – that is a syntax only some CSS preprocessors implement.

Answer (score 0):

You are totally messing all the css

do the following CSS

```
#ss {}
  thead {
    display: block;
  }
  tbody {
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 350px;
  }
  table {
    width: 10px;
  }
  th,
  td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  }
  td {
    width: 60px;
  }
  th {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
  }
  tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #f2f2f2
  }
  tr:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
  }
```

You cannot do like this(nesting CSS )

```
#ss {
  thead {
    display: block;
  }
```

Here's [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6jsptbv8/1/)

```css
#ss {}
  thead {
    display: block;
  }
  tbody {
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 350px;
  }
  table {
    width: 10px;
  }
  th,
  td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  }
  td {
    width: 60px;
  }
  th {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
  }
  tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #f2f2f2
  }
  tr:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
  }
```

```html
<table id="ss">
  <thead>
    <th>No</th>
    <th>Grup</th>
    <th>Barkod</th>
    <th>Urn_Adı</th>

  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr id="a1">

      <td>1</td>
      <td id="a1_0"></td>
      <td id="a1_1"></td>
      <td id="a1_2">NUANS</td>
      <td id="a1_3">NUANS</td>

    <tr id="a2">

      <td>2</td>
      <td id="a2_0"></td>
      <td id="a2_1"></td>
      <td id="a2_2">SKEMER</td>
      <td id="a2_3">WEMSEY</td>

    </tr>

  </tbody>

</table>
```